# What are Stack Overflow's peak hours?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, traffic

At what UTC time(s) is Stack Overflow most used?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [this answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/best-time-to-ask-questions/1314#1314).

(Here's the chart. It's not current, but probably still accurate in relative terms)

[image]

Comment: So 14:00's about when the morning coffee kicks in.

Comment: @squillman: This is in UTC. Note that 14:00Z is 6 AM to 10 AM in the contiguous United States, so it's when Americans wake up.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the latest peak hours for questions, answers, comments and new users on http://sostats.github.io/last24h ([GitHub source page](//github.com/sostats/sostats.github.io)). It shows data collected from the [Stack Exchange API](//api.stackexchange.com/). Time is presented in your browser's time zone. On the screenshot it's CEST (GMT+2):

[image: Stack Overflow Stats - Last 24 hours]

Comment: 276 users in an hour is the high on SO? That doesn't sound right at all... particularly considering that means that 276 users are each creating ~2 questions, ~2.5 answers, and ~9 comments each?

Comment: @Catija It's not active users, it's new users. It's stated on the Github page - https://github.com/sostats/sostats.github.io

Comment: @Zizouz212 Exactly, it new users. Thanks for explaining it and linking to sources.

Comment: @Catija I agree that it was misleading. I changed "Users" to "New Users" to make it clear.