# Question not in peak time or simply not hot enough to attract users to answer it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, unanswered-questions, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Ok, this is happening to me a couple of times now. I ask a perfectly legal question and I get very low views and very few answers:

[Problem redirecting debug output to a file using trace listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568630/problem-redirect-debug-output-to-a-file-using-trace-listener)

[LINQ to XML X-DOM internal implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435577/linq-to-xml-x-dom-internal-implementation)
(this second one was answered when I offered a bounty)

What's going on? Am I asking the questions in the wrong time of the day and they are not on the first page later on?

EDIT: According to this thread:

[What are Stack Overflow's peak hours?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/what-are-stack-overflows-peak-hours)

I asked the question in pretty much the peak time.

Does anyone have some hints on how to make my question more visible and hot, so I can get more answers?

Comment: except that these questions are not old at all

Comment: (And see the links in the right column on the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).)

Comment: Come on, this a very bad question. Your title does not even match the actual question. Search, Sherlock!

Comment: @Arjan - Thanks for your recommendations and advice.

Comment: A little late to the party, but there seems no [best time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329143/4751173) to post a question to get the most possible views.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good resource for anyone that is interested:

[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

It's by Jon Skeet.